# Ways of adding Account Capabilities to Web App

Tags: javascript, php, backend

In the web apps I have built so far that needed account capabilities I have used the following structure : Once signing up, each user would be randomly assigned an ID number. Once the used would sign in, their ID would be stored in a cookie on their device, which would help the website (client-side) know if and who signed in. The problem with this solution is that if, hypothetically, a hacker got access to the database, they wouldn't be able to see the passwords of each user (as I store them hashed), but they would be able to see their ID. Therefore, if that hacker were to change their ID cookie to an ID of another user, they could easily hack them without ever touching their password (or the sign in page for that matter!)

Would you recommend another way of adding account capabilities to my app (when it comes to identifying if and who signed in) without compromising security?

Comment: you could specifically store those ids (or a token that represents the id) in the file system, so at least when db is compromised, they wouldn't be able to login as a user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use user-IDs, use temporary session-IDs. When a user logs in, in that session the user-ID is stored. Then the attacker can still steal the session-ID and use it.

Therefore:

- Invalidate sessions often.
- If there is any important request, force the user to re-authenticate.
- Every (re-)authentication changes the session-ID.
- Secure all transports of the session-IDs (e.g. use cookies, HTTPS only, better not with public certificates but with client certificates).